# Create a Dataframe of All Dates in the year 2015

Tags: r, date

I am interested in creating a dataframe of `Date` values for the year 2015. There would be one row per date. Also, these would have to correspond to their accurate weekday. For example `weekdays()` applied to `2015-01-01` would have a value of `Thursday`. This is because I ultimately want to extract the dates that correspond to Saturdays and Sundays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"),1)
weekdays <- weekdays(dates)

res <- data.frame(dates,weekdays)
res[res$weekdays=="Sunday" | res$weekdays=="Saturday",]

##EDIT thanks to @Jaap 
res[res$weekdays %in% c("Sunday","Saturday"),]

        dates weekdays
3  2015-01-03 Saturday
4  2015-01-04   Sunday
10 2015-01-10 Saturday
11 2015-01-11   Sunday
17 2015-01-17 Saturday
18 2015-01-18   Sunday
```

Comment: @RichardScriven that was not my goal. I was simply trying to explain that an EDIT should have been made instead of a quiet replacement making my comment irrelevant on your answer. Your use of `is.weekend` is something I did not know existed and makes it a much better answer

Comment: you can also use `res[res$weekdays %in% c("Sunday","Saturday"),]` to select the weekenddays